# Object emission controlled by sunlight

Tags: texturing, compositing-nodes, blender-internal-render-engine, light, shaders

I asked this previously for my Earth project but it was never given an answer and was marked as a dupe which it wasn't as the question it was linked to was about textures being controlled by light, not the emission of an object. The effect would be somewhat the same however it shouldn't affect visibility but emission so that the objects emission fades when going dark.

For the atmosphere I'm using 2 spheres. One to act as the atmospheric distance you see where it gets more hazed the further away you look, and another which is the glow itself. For the glow I've found it works best with a volumetric material and have it emit light. The question I would like answered is, how would I control the emission of the volume material with the sun lamp in the scene? I have a strong feeling that nodes can make this happen but I have no clue on what ones would work.

I am working in Blender Render as I haven't figured out a better way to make a good looking Earth in Cycles yet.
[image]

Comment: You can get a super high res could map from Nasa. just scale it down before bringing it into blender.

Comment: Can you post your lighting setup? I think that is the issue.

Comment: There is no lighting set up, just a normal sun. The nodes you see are for the Earth and Night textures. That was just an example of an option I've tried but doesn't work. That picture wasn't the atmosphere set up itself. I know why it's not doing it. It's because my Volume/Atmosphere Sphere is emitting light therefore it shows on the dark side. I just need a be able to make it invisible without getting rid of the emission. It's definitely not a bug/issue so to speak, it's just a lack of knowledge on how to make an object invisible when no main light hits it. The atmosphere light doesn't count.

Comment: You need to stop the emission on the dark side of the planet. I would try a material only effected by your sun lamp controlling the emission.

Comment: That's not an option. The only way I've maintained this effect is because it's self emitting light. That is the reason for the glow. If I just used the sun it would look like it did on my first question; 'Blur a mesh without nodes or cycles?'. There isn't really a better way to create the atmosphere that both gives a nice glow and a distance effect. This has proven to be the best way. Maybe if I create another texture for it, made it a non-emitting object and made it transparent? Who knows, it cannot involve getting rid of the current emission though :/

Comment: My suggestion was to turn of the emission on the dark side of the earth.

Comment: Use the same setup for the surface color to control the emission.

Comment: So, like I've done with the Surface, change the texture of each side, I do for the emission? For the night side, turn emission to 0? And for day turn it up? I'll try but I feel as if the same thing will happen where the Volume material will turn into a black sphere. Any ideas on what material the separator should be then? Would it need to be a volume as well?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16168/discussion-between-stewie-and-giantcowfilms).